# JavaScript resize, if class is different from .close and Width < 990 responsive

Tags: javascript, css

How to perform action: "if resize() function" , if Width < 990 and .close class is not present (nav class=sidebar ), otherwise NOT perform action if Width < 990 and .close is present (nav class=sidebar close ).

Please understand as I'm new to javascript..
Here's the code below with the example, I can't use only css because the complete code has many other css elements, which would make it impossible to do everything with css, I would like an alternative to using javascript.
I already appreciate the help.

I need the javascript to recognize a .close class, if it is activated do nothing, if it is not active and a screen for < 990px, then execute a function to add .close, with that the .sidebar will automatically reduce the size to be responsive without the need to use click text "Close Menu Click"..

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 260px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    
    .sidebar.close{
        background: yellow;
        width: 80px;
    }

    .home-section{
    position: relative;
    background: #E4E9F7;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 260px;
    width: calc(100% - 260px);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    .sidebar.close ~ .home-section{
        left: 80px;
        width: calc(100% - 80px);
    }
    .textClose{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <nav class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu 01</li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 03</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section class="home-section">
        <div class="home-content">
            <span class="textClose">Close Menu Click</span>
        </div>
        <br>
        Body Home...
    </section>


      <script>
        let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
        let sidebarBtn = document.querySelector(".textClose");
        console.log(sidebarBtn);
        sidebarBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
        });

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var element = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

        function resize() {
            if (window.innerWidth < 990 ) {
            element.classList.add('close');
            } else {
            element.classList.remove('close');
            }
        }

        window.onresize = resize;
        window.onload = resize;
        });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you don't want to use css, but you don't want to use javascript either? What do you think you will be able to use if not either of those?

Comment: What is the action you wish to perform - it sounded as though you wanted to set close on the sidebar if the window was less than 990px wide and unset it otherwise. Have I got it right? If so I don't understand what is wrong with your code.

Comment: I need the javascript to recognize the .close class, if it is active do nothing, if it is not active and the screen is < 990px then execute the function, to be responsive I reduce the .sidebar by adding the .close class without click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want this:

```js
if (window.innerWidth < 990 && element.classList.contains('close') === false)
```

Edit:

There should be no loop anymore:

```js
if (window.innerWidth < 990 && element.classList.contains('close') === false) {
    element.classList.toggle("close");
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9zLfwg0h/5/

Comment: that's right, however iso creates a loop between .sidebar and .sidebar .close...
The javascript has to recognize the .close class, if it is active do nothing, if it is not active and the screen is < 990px then execute the function.